# Mysql current timestamp when adding to multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, timestamp

I have 3 tables that I will be adding to on a certain action. All have current_timestamp field in them. 
How do I ensure that the time on all three of these tables are exactly the same ? 
I am using laravel, and I would like to know if using DB:Transaction ensures this.

If not, then what else can I do ?

Comment: Why is this important? The transaction itself should be identifiable via the pk/fk realtionships across the tables, so exact matching by time shouldn't be needed.

Comment: I have a General actions table that stores all actions for a user. Then I have module specific actions (e.g. if he deletes an image , an entry will be stored in general actions , and one that will be added in Image_actions).
I don't have any primary keys between general action and module specific actions, and it makes sense to have the correct timestamps across all tables

Comment: Well, I would do `$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");` and then use it wherever I need it, for example, in the SQL queries. That will ensure that the date and time is the same everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Save the timestamp in a variable and then use that to update/insert in all three tables e.g.

$current_timestamp = time();

**NOTE : i am using PHP's default time function.**